# Why aren't my fonts working on mobile devices?

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts

My fonts are working on the desktop version of my website, however they don't seem to work on a mobile device.

I've tried adding some global css code but it doesn't seem to make a difference. Not sure whether there are faults in the code or not.

```
   @font-face {
   font-family: ‘Rajdhani-Medium’;

   src: 
   url('https://donneverzekeringen.be/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Rajdhani-Medium.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */

   src: 
   url('https://donneverzekeringen.be/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Rajdhani-Medium.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */

   url('https://donneverzekeringen.be/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Rajdhani-Medium.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */

   url('https://donneverzekeringen.be/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Rajdhani-Medium.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */

   url('https://donneverzekeringen.be/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Rajdhani-Medium.svg#svgRajdhani-SMedium') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */

   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal; 
   }
```

Does somebody notice an error in the code above or knows a reason why it isn't working on mobile? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your first line `font-family: ‘Rajdhani-Medium’;` doesn't use the normal single quotes.

Replace `‘’` with `''`.

Comment: Thanks, would've never noticed that. Fixed it but still not working.

Comment: Rest of the code seems fine. You could check two more things: 1. Whether all of the URLs are correct or not, and 2. Whether you are setting the font-family properly in each case or not. Check for more of the bracket issues. Use the Web Inspect element tool to check whether the font is actually being activated but then maybe it is over-ridden by some other CSS style (specific to mobile). WP may disable the fonts if it takes too long to load (internet speed issues).

Comment: Yeah did that, but still no idea. Thanks